PostgreSQL Join on multiple selects gives unexpected result?
I am trying to write a very simple join on select
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('Red'), ('Blue'), ('Green'), ('Yellow')) AS t (colors1)
) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('Red'), ('Blue'), ('Green'), ('Yellow')) AS t (colors2)
) B ON true

What I would like it to do, is return two columns:
Red Red
Blue Blue
Green Green
Yellow Yellow

But instead it returns each one on the left with each one on the right
Red Red
Red Blue
Red Green
Red Yellow (etc)


It appears that you want to join on the color names matching.  If so, then you need a join condition which expresses that, such as:
SELECT A.colors1, B.colors2
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('Red'), ('Blue'), ('Green'), ('Yellow')) AS t (colors1)
) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('Red'), ('Blue'), ('Green'), ('Yellow')) AS t (colors2)
) B
    ON B.colors2 = A.colors1;

Note that your current join condition is simply true, which is basically the same thing as doing a cross join (cartesian product) between the two tables.
